# MS ACCESS UPDATE Query error

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I have a MS ACCESS UPDATE query which I have added in C# code but when it throws an error

"Syntax error in UPDATE Statement" during the run time.

> **string sqlStatement** = "UPDATE Carriers" + "SET CarrierName = @CarrierName, AccountRepName = @AccountRepName, AccountRepContactPhone = @AccountRepContactPhone, AccountRepEmail= @AccountRepEmail, Notes=@Notes" + "WHERE CarrierID = @CarrierID";

kindly help me out in this

regards,
arjun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have space between `Carriers` & `SET`

Statement should be

`string sqlStatement = "UPDATE Carriers" + " SET CarrierName`

Earlier your query was something like this

`sqlStatement = "UPDATE CarriersSET CarrierName"...`.

As you have `CarriersSET`, this is causing error...

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need a space after Carriers (so "UPDATE Carriers "), and before WHERE (so " WHERE CarrierID = @CarrierID";)

```
string sqlStatement = "UPDATE Carriers " + "SET CarrierName = @CarrierName, AccountRepName = @AccountRepName, AccountRepContactPhone = @AccountRepContactPhone, AccountRepEmail= @AccountRepEmail, Notes=@Notes" + " WHERE CarrierID = @CarrierID";
```

This might correct your issue, assuming you are setting all your @ parameters correctly.